# PLSQL trigger to update a record after insert

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to make a database trigger that changes the attributes (STAFFNO, CLASS_DAY, CLASS_TYPE, and ROOMNUM) in a record that has just been inserted or updated into TUTPRAC table to NULL if the class (record entered) either starts Before 9AM or After 6PM.

The Table i want this trigger to affect is called:

TUTPRAC: CLASSID (PK), UNITCODE, STAFFNO, CLASSDAY, CLASSTIME, CLASSTYPE, ROOMNUM

I'm unsure if im on the right track, my code so far:

```
 CREATE TRIGGER CheckBeforeAfterHours
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLASS_TIME ON TUTPRAC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < 9:00 AND > 18:00) THEN
    UPDATE TUTPRAC SET STAFFNO = NULL, CLASS_DAY = NULL, CLASS_TYPE = NULL, ROOMNUM = NULL WHERE CLASS_TIME < 9:00 AND > 18:00;
  END IF;
END CheckBeforeAfterHours;
```

Comment: @CM25 - as OldProgrammer commented, pl/sql is Oracle Database's procedural extension to SQL. Or you really using Oracle Database, or MySQL? Please re-tag you question correctly.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, im using oracle SQLDeveloper. @Mureinik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to update the record being inserted/updated, you do it with a *before* trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CheckBeforeAfterHours
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF CLASS_TIME ON TUTPRAC
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (:NEW.CLASS_TIME < '09:00' AND > '18:00') THEN
     :NEW.STAFFNO := NULL;
     :NEW.CLASS_DAY := NULL;
     :NEW.CLASS_TYPE := NULL;
     :NEW.ROOMNUM := NULL;
  END IF;
END CheckBeforeAfterHours;
```

However, I think it would be better to simply add a constraint to the table for the class times, so you get an error when you try to make an insert or change to an invalid time.

Comment: Oh i see thanks @Gordon Linoff. When i try to use this code though i get a compiler error: `Error(2,26): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following:     ) , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)> and or    as || multiset 
Error(2,26): PLS-00049: bad bind variable '00'`

Comment: @cm25 . . . Your comparison for the `class_time` should be appropriate to the type you are using.  I figured that this was pseudo-code in your question, and just used that logic.  Note that if you have these as strings, then they need to be in the format of "HH:MM" with leading zeros for the hours.

Comment: Sorry silly mistake on my behalf. I have set the CLASS_TIME as varchar (5), should i store it as TIME instead in order to make the check to see if the time is < 09:00 or > 18:00 ?

Comment: @cm25 . . . Does Oracle have a `time` data type?

Comment: having class_time field as varchar im getting the error `Error(2,36): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ">" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>    continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date <a string literal with character set specification>    <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe    <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>    <an alternatively`